# "open -t" vs. "open -ef"

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

the Command:

```
syslog | tail | open -ef
```

works perfectly on my osx 10.8.5 and opens the required lines from syslog in textEdit, however when I run

```
syslog | tail | open -t
```

which should open the same lines in my default text editing program I get nothing and just the lines --No lines in buffer--

I am using MacVim as my default text editor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pipe (`|`) connect the standard output of a program to the standard input of another program. `open` does not read from `stdin`by default but from a file given as argument. It needs the `-f`option to read from the standard input.

That's why your first example work but not your second one.

`syslog | tail | open -tf` works well.

Comment: I actually just figured that out, but you beat me to the answer.  Thanks